# New KMM project does not contain Assets.xcassets

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I created a new KMM project and got to the point where I wanted to add some images to the iPhone app. At this point I noticed that there was no Assets.xcassets file. I created a brand new project to double check I did not deleted it on accident and I did not. Is there a different way of doing this on KMM or do I need to manually add the Assets file?

Comment: If you would like to discuss adding this file to the KMM's project wizard, consider filing a feature request at Kotlin's issue tracker: kotl.in/issue

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KMA-343 here's the link if anybody is interested

Answer (score 1):

Not really and I wouldn't really expect it, they might add it to the new project wizard or not, depending on which is the more general use-case for KMM I think.

The purpose of KMM is more sharing business logic and while they have bridging plugins and other tools for easier development probably it's still the best to work with Xcode for iOS platform specific things.

Answer (score 0):

KMM does not create the entire android nor ios with it's asset you have to add the assets to it from xcode.